# Strange behavior with str_to_date, possible mixing of tables?

Tags: mysql, str-to-date

I have an issue with this query and cannot figure out where the problem is coming from. 
I am trying to run: `update earnings_history set`Date_formatted`=  STR_TO_DATE(`temp_date`, '%m/%d/%Y');` to convert my strings to dates, but I get this error.

```
Error Code: 1292. Incorrect datetime value: '2015-02-29' for column 'Date_formatted' at row 5610
```

Yet this query: `select temp_date from earnings_history where`temp_date`REGEXP '[-]';` finds no rows.

I use the %Y-%m-%d formatted in an entirely different table, yet they seem to be mixing?

Comment: what is your `earnings_history.Date_formatted` type?

Comment: I tried both date and datetime

Comment: you don't have to try, you just should know. so what is your type? and `temp_date` by the way?

Comment: Right now its date. Temp_date is varchar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll find you have a `temp_date` field set to `02/29/2015` in your `earnings_history` table.

Your `STR_TO_DATE()` call is specifying format of a `'%m/%d/%Y'`. It's finding a date with that format and parsing it to a standard SQL date format of `'%Y-%m-%d'`. Then, it tries to insert that date into your typed field. That type won't take an invalid date, so when it sees the invalid date of `2015-02-29`, it throws the error. You don't have a `%Y-%m-%d`-formatted date in your table; you have an invalid date in your expected format of `%m/%d/%Y`.

Comment: Yea I just discovered somehow the dates got mixed up when I entered the data in. Trying to input the data again now. Thanks!